# How to achieve rank in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve rank in SSRS?, Scenario is below

- I have one measure, for example sum(revenue) by Country.
- I have a table, it has two columns, one is country another one is rank
  for rank column
- I need to display rank for each country - if a country is has the max revenue I need to give rank as 1, next rank 2 like that

I tried sorting, but is gives me the sum(revenue) not rank

Can you please tell me how to do this in SSRS

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1):

SELECT Country, Sales, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sales DESC) AS Rank FROM [mytable] ORDER BY Rank DESC

Comment: hello dsp  thank you so much for the replyis there any other way to do at report level, my country should be in alphabetic order and rank should display by revenue

Comment: ```SELECT Country, [Rank]
FROM  (
    SELECT Country, Sales, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sales DESC) AS [Rank]
    FROM  [mytable] 
   ) X
ORDER BY Country ASC
 ```